# Index en array de arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo esta estructura de datos

```
const array = [
    [
        {
            "a": 166,
            "b": 436,
            "c": true
        },
        {
            "a": 164,
            "b": 436,
            "c": true
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "a": 165,
            "b": 434,
            "c": true
        },
        {
            "a": 167,
            "b": 434,
            "c": false
        }
    ]
]
```

Estoy intentando sacar el index del array que contiene el `b = 434`, que en este caso sería el 1, pero no lo consigo.

¿Alguna pauta? Al ser un array de arrays, creo que algo se me escapa

Comment: En realidad tienes dos elementos con `b = 434` (los dos del segundo elemento en el array principal), así que uno de ellos por ejemplo podrías mostrarlo con `console.log (array[1][0]);` y el otro con `console.log (array[1][1]);`

Comment: Una forma de verlo podría ser `x = array(array(obj, ...), ...)`, entonces `x[n] == array(obj, ...)` y `x[n][m] == obj`.

Comment: Cuando dices que estas tratando de sacar el index, te refieres a que el elemento 434 podría estar en cualquier posicion del array y necesitas "encontrar" cual es? O lo que dices es que no entiendes como acceder a los datos en el ejemplo que pones? y otra pregunta, ese elemento 434 podría existir en varios indices del array principal? o todos los elementos dentro de ese indice tendrian el mismo valor de b (asi como en tu ejemplo)?

Comment: @Pipe Exacto, el 434 podría estar en cualquier elemento del array. Por lo tanto, si que es verdad que ahora mismo, esta en el index Array[1], pero podría estar en cualquiera y yo lo que quiero saber es en que index está

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer esto puedes recurrir a utilizar un `findIndex` unido con un `find`, pero devolverá la primera posición del array con el campo `b === 434`.

```js
const array = [
    [
        {
            "a": 166,
            "b": 436,
            "c": true
        },
        {
            "a": 164,
            "b": 436,
            "c": true
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "a": 165,
            "b": 434,
            "c": true
        },
        {
            "a": 167,
            "b": 434,
            "c": false
        }
    ]
];

const filtered = array.findIndex(item => item.find( element => element.b === 434 ));
console.log(array[filtered][0])
console.log(array[filtered][1])
```

Esto devolverá el index del array que contiene algún elemento con la propiedad `b: 434` y devolverá el array completo de objetos.

Como no se exactamente que buscas hacer ahí tendrás el index para poder acceder a esa posición del array y dentro tendrás varias posiciones, las cuales también podrás filtrar de forma que, continuando con el snippet anterior:

```
array[filtered].filter(it => it.c === true);
```

Comment: Es una idea muy buena la verdad, pero meterle funciones Arrow... buff, creo que es alguien que está empezando, y si no tiene clara la estructura de un array de arrays... las funciones arrow ya...

Comment: No, no estoy empezando :D. Pero una cosa, ¿esto conservaría el index del objeto inicial? Entiendo que no, tendríamos un nuevo array con los datos filtrados no? Quiero decir, en el ejemplo que os he dejado, el index del array que contiene el valor, es el 1. Pero en el caso que comentas, sería el 0, ¿no?

Comment: con el primer arrayIndex tendrias todo el array a tu disposicion... el segundo ejemplo que te puso es si quieres obtener ciertos elementos del array encontrado. Pero creo que el primer ejemplo basta para tu necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta rápida para esta pregunta viene a ser esta: `array[1][0].b`, pero la idea es que se entienda el concepto de por qué es así.

En este caso tienes un Array de Arrays de un objeto cuyos atributos son `a`, `b` y `c`. Vamos a ir de un array simple hasta llegar a esa estructura para que se entienda bien.

El objetivo va a ser siempre obtener el 434.

1. Primer caso tenemos: `const array = [0, 434, 543]`, es decir un array normal, para obtener el 434 es con un índice simple en `array`:

`array[1]` obtendría el resultado 434.

2.En este caso vamos a tener: `const array = [[0], [0,434], [543]]`, es decir, un array de arrays de estrutuctura básica, en este caso enteros, por lo tanto... con dos índices nos valdría para obtener 434.

`array[1][1]` obtendría el resultado 434.

3. Este caso es el tuyo:

   ```
     const array = [
         [
             {
                 "a": 166,
                 "b": 436,
                 "c": true
             },
             {
                 "a": 164,
                 "b": 436,
                 "c": true
             }
         ],
         [
             {
                 "a": 165,
                 "b": 434,
                 "c": true
             },
             {
                 "a": 167,
                 "b": 434,
                 "c": false
             }
         ]
     ]
   ```

Es decir, un array de arrays de una estructura compleja cuyos atributos son `a`, `b` y `c`, es decir, aquí tenemos que entrar 3 niveles, dos a nivel de índice y uno más a nivel de atributo, luego el índice quedaría, ya que está en el atributo b del objeto del primer subArray del segundo array principal:

`array[1][0].b`

Edito: con esta respuesta obtendrías el primer 434, para obtener el segundo es muy sencillo, está en el atributo b del objeto del segundo subArray del segundo array:

`array[1][1].b`

Comment: Lo primero, agradecer tu respuesta. Lo segundo, creo que no me he expresado bien. lo que quiero es saber el id (index) del padre del array que contiene dicho valor. Pero de forma dinámica, no busco acceder al dato, como me cuentas en la respuesta.